# How to make a file downloadable in FastAPI with supporting multiple extension types?

Tags: python, fastapi, httpresponse, mime-types, media-type

I am fetching contents of files from a server. The server contains all types of files like json, text, etc.

```
@app.get("myurl")
def get_file(myfilename):
  mydata=fetch_file_from_server(myfilename)
  headers = {"content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\"{}\"".format(myfilename)}
  return Response(content=mydata, media_type="application/json", headers=headers)
```

I tried with `media_type="application/json"` but it seems it will only work with JSON files.

I expect the file to be downloaded irrespective of the extension.

I am currently using `media_type="application/tar+gzip"`, but not sure if this is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73672334/17865804) as well (under **MIME Type** section)

Comment: If you don't want to provide a specific content-type, use `application/octet-stream` - its only definition is "arbitrary binary data", which generally tells the browser "I'm not saying this is anything specific, but treat it as binary".